# Use sed with regex and (

Tags: php, regex, bash, sed

I have a function in php file:

```
_t('', 'Award received')
```

I've made a regex, which finds first part of the function _t(''

[See Regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/hW1qQ1/1)

Now, I want to replace that function with something else (actually, I want to add argument to the function).

From console:

```
grep -rl "_t('', 'Award received')" application | xargs sed -i "s/_t\s*\(\s*['|\"](\s*\s*)['|\"]/test/g"
```

Sed doesn't want to make replacement, it says: "( or ( without a pair", so it looks like it is trying to look for bracket inside regex...

How can I use sed with regex expressions containing brackets?

EDIT: 
I have test string which I want to replace:

```
_t('124', 'Test')
```

When I make simple replacement

```
sed -i -E 's/124JHGJH/124/g'
```

it works fine.

But if I try to replace whole string, with parenthesis and other, it just hangs out and not responding...

```
sed -i -E 's/_t\(\'124JHGJH\'/124/g'
```

Comment: In "plain" sed, capturing parentheses are `\(` and`\)` (with the backslashes) and `(` and `)` are just characters ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Regular-expression-syntaxes.html#Regular-expression-syntaxes)). If you use `sed -r` (or `sed -E`) then `(` and `)` are capturing parentheses, and you have to escape parentheses to match them as characters

Comment: cant make it work :(((((

see edit

Comment: You cannot embed a single quote in a single quoted string, even with backslashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take note of the difference between `\(` and `(` in sed regex.

To add a new parameter at then end of the function call:

```
echo "_t('', 'Award received')" | sed 's/_t([^)]\+/&, new_param/'
```

```
_t('', 'Award received', new_param)
```

The regex is:

- `-t(` = literal characters
- `[^)]\+` = one or more non-`)` characters

The next character will be the function's close paren, so that's where I assume you want to insert the new parameter. I use `&` in the replacement to put the text matched by the regex in its place.

This will break if there's a literal sting argument that contains a close paren character.

Comment: how do I add index as first parameter? sorry for stupidity, 4 hours spent on that sed (( I need _t('12345', 'Award received')

Comment: `sed "s/_t('/&12345/"`

Comment: thank you thank you thank you )))
I thought i'd never go home today

Answer (score 1):

using markers in sed with the regular expression argument

```
sed -r 's/(_t[^)]+)(\))/\1,new_parameter\2/g'

`(_t[^)]+)` #matches _t and all characters before the last parenthesis. Mark this pattern

(\)) #matches the last parenthesis and mark this pattern

\1,new_parameter\2/ #substitute the first marked pattern, then place the new parameter followed by the second pattern marked, which the the last parenthesis
```

example

```
echo "_t('', 'Award received')"|sed -r 's/(_t[^)]+)(\))/\1,new_parameter\2/g'
```

output

```
_t('', 'Award received',new_parameter)
```